# Accept self-signed certificate with Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, certificate, overloading, self-signed

I tried different ways but without success.
With some example from websites I get the following errors.

> Argument label [forTrust:] do not match any available overloads:

[image]

How can I fix this or use another method?

I'm with Swift 3 and XCode 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, this parameter has been renamed `trust` instead of `forTrust`.